# Speech Recognition code not working, how to fix this?

Tags: python, text-to-speech

```
import speech_recognition as sr

listener = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            print("working")
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice) #this is the line causing error
            print("working")
            print(command)
```

This is a speech to text program, using the speech recognition api. Due to one specific line of code the whole program isnt working. Ive spent over 6 hours trying to identify and fix the error, and all ive figured out is that its a problem with my computer( dont know what) sice it works on other computer.
The Error its giving is:
"ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

I tried removing my firewall, changing the server numbers or smth, and some other stuff.
Nothing worked!
The program works on other computers, so smth wrong with my computer.
But what, i cant understand

Comment: maybe server doesn't like you IP address and it gives `"closed by the remote host"`

Comment: What does that mean, and how could  fix that?

Comment: I only guess. Server may think you are hacker and it doesn't allow to access it. Frankly, It may not have good explanation. If you would [search message in Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-lm&q=%22ConnectionResetError%3A+%5BWinError+10054%5D+An+existing+connection+was+forcibly+closed+by+the+remote+host%22) then you would see that different people had this problem with different pages and they can't find explanation. One page suggest to [use some command](https://github.com/VFrontDe-Org/ESXi-Customizer-PS/issues/15#issuecomment-656938625) but they don't know why it works.